# Do we need to increase the required delete votes?

Tags: discussion, questions, moderation, vote-to-delete

Originally close votes required was 3 then 4 now 5 as the number of people who could close increased. Not so long ago 10k+ rep was limited to the first page of users. It's now onto page 6 I think.

Is it time to increase the delete votes from the current 3?

Comment: Yes. The minimum should be 5 delete votes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, this got deleted, which I vehemently disagreed with

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598/what-is-the-worst-interviewee-answer-closed

So it does happen. But it is rare, at least right now.

We're considering putting in limits where posts that are voted **very** highly (as in, 50+) are essentially "protected" from deletion by anyone other than a moderator.

Comment: I'm honestly surprised at that. I looked at that question and ist a discussion, not a question. It might be a popular discussion topic but its not a real question (imho).

Comment: May I add another idea?  How about instead of making it protected, make it require more votes to close?  If a question has 50 up votes, that it requires 15 people or something?  That way moderators don't have to get involved all the time, and if that number of people with a high enough rep (like 1% of the pop has the ability to do that) maybe it should and they can still do so?

Comment: Deletion of these questions is a form of trolling.

Comment: Hi Jeff, now that it's over 3 years later and your knowledge of Q&A has expanded, do you still take this stance on that deleted question, that it shouldn't be deleted?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's really a problem.. Have you seen cases where things have been wrongly deleted? As Shog9 says, there's not much being deleted..

It requires 8 votes to delete something (close votes + delete votes), and it can just as easily be restored.. >3k users can dispute the closing of a question (and by extension, the deletion) by voting to reopen it, as can everyone else can via comments..

There may be more users with 10k rep, but anyone who has spent the time to get to 1000 upvotes on their content (ignoring the daily-rep-cap, down-votes, community wiki etc) is *probably* fairly.. invested in the site. It takes just as much effort to get to 10k rep now as it was when there was no >10k users - I don't see why new "10kians" should be any less trustworthy..

Answer (score 1):

Can't say I've seen a tremendous number of posts being deleted, save for those occasions when Jeff goes through and cleans house. If it ain't broke...