# Make it harder for popular question to be closed

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, vote-to-close, popular-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should popular questions be so easy to delete?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8282/should-popular-questions-be-so-easy-to-delete)

Make it harder for popular question to be closed.

Users vote on question not only by means of giving their vote (not all of them even are able to do so) but to much extend also (in many cases **only**) by digging it among thousands of others and just **viewing**. Respect this kind of *voting*, please.

Comment: Sounds like you're going with celebrity justice here. That is, those who are famous are served by a different set of rules than the rest of the plebs.

Comment: declined as 'duplicate'

Answer (score 4):

Questions usually get closed for good reasons; and it's not exactly easy to close question. Popular questions should not get any preferential treatment. If it really is that good it can always be reopened.

Comment: Moreover, it's easy enough to reopen a question (and usually gets done so quickly if a question has been closed against popular opinion).

Comment: It's as easy to close a question as it is to reopen. And if the question has merit, it will stay open.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point is that these are completely different axes of voting.

If we make upvotes counter close votes, that conflates and confuses the concepts of a) editorial control and b) popularity. They're different.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to step out of line here and say that I think that there is some merit in the original post.

Of course some questions should be closed, obvious spam for example. However there tends to be a little (how can I say this politely) sternness from the people with editorial control.

There are two ways of viewing this. One is that people who can vote questions can do so by virtue of a high rep and that was bestowed upon them by the community, so their will is the will of the community.

The second way to view this is while people who can close posts have a high reputation their will may not be that of the majority of users. This is evident if popular questions are being closed.

It is very delicate ground to tread getting the balance right. Especially as more and more users become moderators. It will be a struggle to keep the site accessible for new users while keeping old users happy. Making popular questions harder to close (and unpopular ones easier)  is a way to keep the moderators and the newer users on the same page.

I guess I don't buy that they are completely different axes, often there is some judgement behind why a question is closed, should lower rep people have no say in if they want a question on their site.

**Edit**

It may help to take score into account when there are close/reopen wars going on (ie when the editors can't decide)

Comment: Is there any evidence that really popular questions are actually being closed? (I haven't checked.)

Comment: That is a good point. I have seen one of mine go that way, but even I admit it was borderline. But as they are closed I don't know how we could tell.

Answer (score 1):

Some popular questions need to be closed and moved to MSO or another trilogy site.

You have a point about popular questions being closed. However, the reopen vote mostly resolves this. Personally, I'd like a reopen vote opportunity before the question is closed at all, so it can prevented in the first place.