# Why can a question with more than 10 upvotes be closed by 5 votes?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shouldn't popular questions require more votes to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77561/shouldnt-popular-questions-require-more-votes-to-close)

Isn't it a little bit unfair that a good question on Stack Overflow with more than 10 upvotes can be closed by 5 votes?

In addition, I have evidenced cases that a user has answered a question, but voted to close it as well! Is it fair?

Comment: Which question? Questions which are not suitable (off-topic, not constructive, etc), as defined in the [faq] can be closed.

Comment: Was going to flag as a duplicate of [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24697/make-it-harder-for-popular-question-to-be-closed), which was declined, but it was also closed as a duplicate of a request that was implemented. I'm confus.

Comment: Q&A: one question per post, please. (That said: I feel the 2nd question is a duplicate of [Closing Etiquette: Why Do Some Answer *and* Close?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4283/closing-etiquette-why-do-some-answer-and-close))

Answer (score 8):

It can be closed by 5 users, also reopened again by 5 different users. Votes are not an indicator if a question is on-topic for a site.

Wildly popular questions don't always mean they are on-topic or suitable for Stack Exchange. Nothing's fair in life.

Comment: whee edge case again! Answer posted after getting closed! /cc @Arjan

Comment: And an upvote for using these sites to their limits ;-)