# Why is this question locked?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, locked

[What is your “best friend” as a programmer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700205/what-is-your-best-friend-as-a-programmer)

I don't understand why this question was locked, or what that means. Is it going to be deleted? I liked it! Why didn't Bill the Lizard leave a comment?

Comment: Locking it keeps the question from being closed or deleted. Learn how the site works before throwing a tantrum.

Comment: It survived for what, 9 months? People were probably sick of seeing it always pop to the top of the screen, and after 197 answers nobody will be adding anything of value to it

Comment: Re the last line; nobody is doing anything of the sort...

Comment: The post has historical value, but there was nothing -- and I mean nothing -- you could possibly add to it. Did you read all 197 answers? Why the butthurt over it? I'm with Diago, I voted to close as blatantly offensive -- it's one thing to disagree with a mod's decision, but be respectful toward them and management when you do.

Answer (score 13):

Sorry, I should have left a comment on that one.  It was flagged for moderator attention and I locked it for the reasons Marc already pointed out.

I'm definitely not against humor.  I'd have to go through and delete some of my own old posts if that were the case (depending on your definition of "humor").  In my defense though, this question currently has 197 answers.  Around half of them (by my rough estimate) are some variation of either "Google" or "caffeine".  Questions like this tend to get locked once all of the original punchlines have been taken.

> That is even worst that people are voting to reopen the question and question is locked...

The comments you're reading where people are asking for the question to be reopened are old comments.  Check the dates.  I actually forgot to close the question before locking it, so voting to reopen is impossible.

> Now if this question is locked or deleted then I will suggest StackOverflow to remove link of "Feedback always welcome" from the bottom, its no use to even keep it there.

Your feedback **is** always welcome.  You got the attention of 3 moderators (so far) with this meta post.  Anything that moderators can do (with the exception of merging questions) can be undone.  Everything we do is logged for the core SO team to review.  If we do something that you think is wrong, you're perfectly welcome, even encouraged, to bring it up so we can discuss it.  I volunteered to be a moderator because I want to help make SO better for the community, not because I want to screw it up.  If I mess something up, I want to hear about it so I can correct it.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what Diago said, this is an issue that has been discussed, **by** the community (after being raised directly by Jeff), here on meta:

> [Should old, very popular closed questions be deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33786/should-old-very-popular-closed-questions-be-deleted)

Closing+Locking seems to be the agreed way of keeping the old (yet off-topic) content alive, but prevent it being a constant distraction of edits etc.

Answer (score 6):

Bill will probably reply himself however from what I can see it is most likely locked because of the amount of unnecessary edits and it was most likely reported by other users. I would have done exactly the same, as the question has had a lot of unnecessary edits, which we refer to as an edit war. These posts are locked when the edits become out of hand, which was the case here I would assume.

As for Bill's action, any Diamond Moderator can intervene and manage a question when they deem it necessary. SO only has 2 Diamond Moderators apart from the Site Owners. The 10K mods which there is a lot more of, do not have the ability to lock a post.

As for your rant, I find it blatantly offensive. If you are taking 1 question this seriously, then SO is NOT the place for you. I personally fail to see how this question adds any value to SO altogether. I directly violates the FAQ which clearly states that this is a Q&A site and not a discussion forum, and extended discussions and best of type questions are highly discouraged.

Comment: I don't think that's why Bill closed it, but +1 for your last paragraph.

Comment: I was in complete agreement with your post, then I read your last paragraph. Why go there?  Offensive?  The OP has a question and voiced their opinion.  If you get offended that easily, I'll be blatantly offended by that...

Comment: I think Diago is frustrated because people do treat some mods like crap when they get their feelings hurt

Comment: @Chester: Read the rant up top. It **is** blatantly offensive. Like I said in my other comment, it's OK to disagree with a mod's decision, but be respectful when you do. OP was blatantly disrespectful, mocked the mod, and accused the mod of having a "God complex." I applaud Diago for calling this question out as what it is.

Comment: I'm not saying that his entire post was flawed, just his last statement. If you are goin to be a mod, you need to be above the games that people play on this site. People pull the offensive card way too much. The other mod responses in this post are right on.

Answer (score 1):

Wow... Akash is very upset about this -- he even emailed me via my blog to ask me to comment. I didn't know I was that important! :D

Akash:

I can't add anything to what's been said by Diago, Bill and Marc. Although I agree that many questions get closed that shouldn't, mostly by the 3k to 10k crowd who are flexing their newfound power to vote a thread closed, it doesn't help to get upset if a question you like is closed. If you have the rep, vote to reopen. If not, earn the rep, then vote.

In the case of this locking, I agree with Bill's intent. The thread had outlived any usefulness or humor and had degenerated into a bunch of "me too" comments. Locking was a sensible thing, and the thread isn't gone, it's just not being updated. Anyone trawling through the archives can read it and enjoy it; they just can't answer it themselves.